# React js amp support

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

What is AMP SUPPORT and how to add it to react pages? Please somebody help... I need to know it urgently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to add code into your website. If my assumption is correct then you can use https://prismjs.com/ which is a syntax highlighter library, but i believe there are others available as well (For instance https://highlightjs.org/) .

Comment: Thank You so much i just wanted to know if there's some way

Comment: Can you tell how to apply this in my code like for java ?

public class random {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, This Is JAVA Program");
    }
}

i want to add this code

Comment: Over here it say how to do it https://prismjs.com/#basic-usage

Comment: highlight js dark theme and its usage please?